# How to create a comma separated value using Cursor of MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, string-concatenation

I want to formulate a variable from a cursor with a final value something like: "1,2,3". Following is the simple stored proc:

```
    OPEN cursor1;
    BEGIN
        LOOP1: LOOP
        FETCH cursor1 INTO main_account_id;
        IF no_more_rows THEN
            CLOSE cursor1;
            LEAVE LOOP1;
        END IF;
        // Here I want to achieve something like "1,2,3" from main_account_id
        END LOOP LOOP1;
    END;
```

Comment: "formulate a variable" - which variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define your variable as NULL:

```
SET @comma_sep_value = NULL;
```

Then use [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) in the loop:

```
SET @comma_sep_value = CONCAT_WS(',', @comma_sep_value, @next_element);
```

There will be no trailing comma, so no TRIM will be required.

Comment: This is more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following is the pseudo of how I achieved it:

```
SET @comma_sep_value = "";
OPEN cursor1;
BEGIN
    LOOP1: LOOP
    FETCH cursor1 INTO main_account_id;
    IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE cursor1;
        LEAVE LOOP1;
    END IF;
    SET @comma_sep_value = CONCAT(@comma_sep_value,main_account_id,","); 
    END LOOP LOOP1;
END;
SET @comma_sep_value = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM @comma_sep_value); 
SELECT @comma_sep_value as final_val;
```

Note: The second last line is to trim trailing comma.